# How to connect to an already open Terminal session on another Mac

Tags: terminal, network, ssh

I am running Mac OS X 10.7 on a MBP and OS X 10.8 on a Mac Mini. I can connect to the Mini via ssh without any issues.
I am running GNS3 (Network simulation) on the Mini and have configured it so that when I connect to one of my routers via the console, a Terminal window is opened.

On Linux I can connect to a remote terminal sessions if it's using screen or by connecting to the tty.

**I would like to connect to the remote Terminal already open on my Mini from my MBP.**

Do I need to run the equivalent of screen to be able to do this?

When I do a ps -aux on the Mini I get:

```
885   0.0  0.4  2622240  18368   ??  S     2:19pm   0:16.27 /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal
-psn_0_561289
```

Is there a way to connect to this terminal from a remote computer when I am connected via ssh?

What does -psn_0_561289 mean?

Can this identifier be used to connect to this terminal?

Comment: The equivalent of screen on the Mac is screen. Have you tried doing it the same way you do it on Linux?

Comment: Indeed, I have just posted my own answer. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Screen is the best way to do it.  The command is available under both Mac OS X 10.7 and 10.8.

I configured the console sessions in GNS3 to use Terminal and screen with the following command:

```
/usr/bin/osascript -e 'tell application "terminal" to do script with command "screen telnet %h %p ; exit"'
```

This can be found in **GNS3>Preferences>General>Terminal Settings**

Then I list the screen sessions in my remote ssh session with the command:

`screen -list`

and... finally connect to the required router with:

`screen -D -r <name of session obtained with "screen -list" above>`

Comment: A more modern and powerful alternative / replacement for `screen` command is [`tmux`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux).